# How to reshape multiple rows to a single row with several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

This may seem an obvious questions for someone who has practice with `reshape` package but I'm trying to get use to its functions and I can't figure out the right syntax!

Let's have the following data frame,

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:12,ncol=3),row.names=letters[1:4])

  X1 X2 X3
a  1  5  9
b  2  6 10
c  3  7 11
d  4  8 12
```

how can we bind the rows into columns in order to get the following result?

```
  X1.a X2.a X3.a X1.b X2.b X3.b X1.c X2.c X3.c X1.d X2.d X3.d
     1    5    9    2    6   10    3    7   11    4    8   12
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This too would work:

```
vec <- c(t(df))
names(vec) <- c(outer(colnames(df), rownames(df), paste, sep="."))

## > vec
## X1.a X2.a X3.a X1.b X2.b X3.b X1.c X2.c X3.c X1.d X2.d X3.d 
##    1    5    9    2    6   10    3    7   11    4    8   12
```

Comment: ahh...!!!! I should've thought of `outer` when I had the solution with `expand.grid`. Very nice! (+1) from me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want it as a vector, there's no need for `reshape` perse. You can just `unlist` it and then use `setNames` to set the names accordingly.

```
df.t <- as.data.frame(t(df))
vec <- unlist(df.t, use.names=FALSE) # gives a vector not matrix/data.frame
vec.names <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(rownames(df.t), colnames(df.t)), sep="."))
vec <- setNames(vec, vec.names)

# X1.a X2.a X3.a X1.b X2.b X3.b X1.c X2.c X3.c X1.d X2.d X3.d 
#    1    5    9    2    6   10    3    7   11    4    8   12
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one:

```
m <- melt(cbind(df, rn=rownames(df)), id.vars='rn')
cast(m, ~ rn + variable)

##   value a_X1 a_X2 a_X3 b_X1 b_X2 b_X3 c_X1 c_X2 c_X3 d_X1 d_X2 d_X3
## 1 (all)    1    5    9    2    6   10    3    7   11    4    8   12
```

Or as Arun indicates, `acast` gives a matrix (without the additional `value` column):

```
acast(m, . ~ variable+rn)
##      X1_a X1_b X1_c X1_d X2_a X2_b X2_c X2_d X3_a X3_b X3_c X3_d
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

(Note that the permutation is in the other order, due to the formula being flipped.)

Comment: I'd use `reshape2` with `acast(m, . ~ variable + rn)`.

Comment: Something to be said for that, @Arun.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get what you mean :).

Comment: You can flip the results by doing `acast(m, . ~rn+variable)`

Comment: @Emer I believe that I wrote that above.

Comment: names(x) <- gsub("_",".",names(x),fixed=TRUE)

Comment: @Brandon I think you'd need to use `colnames` here as in `colnames(x) <- gsub("_", "\\.", colnames(x))` so I eliminated the `fixed=TRUE` to make up for the extra characters that would need to be typed with `colnames` over `names` :-)